# Create a search bar next to label in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm new to iOS development. I created a label and search bar by using the following codes.

```
UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,40,320,40)];

UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
```

But I want search bar placed to the right of label. How can I achieve this through coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Describe your issue more detailed and let us know, what you have tried already.

Comment: if put 320 width and run in 5s then it's impossible. so try this for label CGRectMake(0,40,100,40) and for searchBar frame CGRectMake(105,40,100,40)

Comment: My problem is search bar covers the label but I want to show the label and search view like |label|(20-padding)|searchbar|.

Answer (score 0):

Change the position according to your requirements.

```
UILabel* lbNavTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,80,40)];


UISearchBar *searchBar  = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(85, 20, 120, 44)];
```

Also apply Auto-layout for display same frame for all devices.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't hardcode frames. With the proliferation of different screen sizes and presentation styles, you're going to end up redoing it later anyway. The preferred approach is to use autolayout constraints. You can generate them programatically and attach them to the views, but if you value your sanity, you'll be much better off using a storyboard to lay out the view and their constraints.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2